# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Abc.greetings()V

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

In my java code I need to call a method present in .dll library

I have tried a lot on this, using jna and also by using System.loadLIbraray().
First I create my java as shown below, after compiling I generated header file Abc.h using javah.

I placed Abc.h is my visual studio project and created one cpp file
Then I build the project which created the .dll file

```java
public class Abc {
      public native void greetings();
       static {
         System.loadLibrary("ClassLibrary1");
         System.out.println("library loaded");
       }
      public static void main(String args[])
       {      Abc abc = new Abc();
            abc.greetings();
        }
       }
```

**Abc.h**

```c
      /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */

      #include <jni.h>

      /* Header for class Abc */
      #ifndef _Included_Abc
      #define _Included_Abc
      #ifdef __cplusplus
      extern "C" {
      #endif

      JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Abc_greetings  (JNIEnv *, jobject);
      #ifdef __cplusplus
      }
      #endif
      #endif
```

**Abc.cpp**

```
      #include "Abc.h"
      #include <stdio.h>
       JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Abc_greetings(JNIEnv *env,jobject jobj) {   
        printf("Hello from Visual C++!");
      }
```

When I am running java program, its giving error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Abc.greetings()V

Please help me in solving this

Comment: Most probably your `dll` is not on `PATH`. Make sure to add location of your `dll` to `PATH` variable inside environment settings. Also, make sure that architecture of your `dll` matches one of your `Java` installation.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure "ClassLibrary1.dll" contains your `Java_Abc_greetings`? Does dependency walker confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused. The `printf` call is an edit by yourself? Because the JNI boilerplate code is auto-generated, so this should not be there. JNI is looking via the interface for a known function `greetings()` which it cannot find. Thus the exception. This function needs to exist somewhere in the C++ library.

This is what JNI boilerplate code may look like:

**Native function called via Java:**

```
public static void helloWorldJNI()
{
    helloWorld();
}

private static native void helloWorld();
```

**Corresponding native code .h / .cpp:**

```
static void helloWorld();
```

```
void somenamespace::UtilitiesNative::helloWorld()
{
    LOG_DEBUG << "[JNI HELLO WORLD]";
}
```

**Autogenerated JNI boilerplade, you do not edit this:**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_data_jni_UtilitiesNative_helloWorld(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls) {
    jthrowable exc = NULL;
    try {
        somenamespace::UtilitiesNative::helloWorld();
    } catch (...) {
        exc = JavaCPP_handleException(env, 19);
    }

    if (exc != NULL) {
        env->Throw(exc);
    }
}
```

Note that the latter is not written by myself, but generated by JNI. Also note that it checks data, then accesses `helloWorld()` from the auto-generated method.

Comment: Abc.cpp is created and written by me. The method signature I copied from Abc.h file. As per my knowledge and what I found on google says same thing. Generate header file and then copy method signature and write method code yourself.

Comment: Cannot refute this, but also cannot attest to that. In my implementation there is no JNI `.h` file, only an auto-generated JNI `cpp`. It provides access to my C++ method from Java. What i read online confirms this, *e.g.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface, see *Design*.

Answer (score 0):

After so much investigation, I found the problem with my complation steps.
When I compiled with basic cl (clang) compiler, and generated the dll. It works fine.

cl "abc.cpp" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\include\win32" -FeClassLibrary1.dll -MD -LD